No sound after upgrade from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04
I have upgraded my computer operating system from Ubuntu 22.04 to Ubuntu 24.04. I have no sound on the computer after the upgrade.  Everything worked fine before. I have read various forums on the subject but have not been able to solve the problem.  Below is some information that may be helpful.
uname -all
Linux agold163858 5.14.0-1054-oem #61-Ubuntu SMP Fri Oct 14 13:05:50 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

aplay -l
aplay: device_list:277: no soundcards found...

lspci | grep -i Audio
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Tiger Lake-LP Smart Sound Technology Audio Controller (rev 20)

sudo dmesg | grep -i audio


[    0.204508] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio) 
[    4.365212] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if info 0x040380 
[    4.374340]    sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Digital mics found on Skylake+    platform, using SOF driver 
[    4.375723] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl    0000:00:1f.3: DSP detected with PCI class/subclass/prog-if 0x040380 
[    4.566359] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915]) 
[    4.911926]    sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: use msi interrupt mode 
[    4.933067] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: hda codecs found, mask 5 
[    4.933070] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: using HDA    machine driver skl_hda_dsp_generic now 
[    4.933074]    sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: DMICs detected in NHLT tables:    4 
[    4.933463] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: Direct    firmware load for intel/sof/sof-tgl.ri failed with error -2 
[    4.933466] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: request firmware intel/sof/sof-tgl.ri failed err: -2 
[    4.933469]    sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: you may need to download the    firmware from https://github.com/thesofproject/sof-bin/ 
[    4.933471] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3: error: failed to load DSP firmware -2 
[    4.933860] sof-audio-pci-intel-tgl 0000:00:1f.3:    error: sof_probe_work failed err: -2

I would greatly appreciate any help with this issue.
Thanks,
Alex

I was facing the same issue, in setting app shows no playback device. And eventually fixed by reinstalling ubuntu-desktop package.
sudo apt install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop^


Thank you for your reply. By default in my system kernel 5.14.0-1054-oem is selected. I noticed that if in the Adavanced Ubuntu menu during  startup  I select kernel 6.11.0-061100-generic then sound works well...

I solved it this way:
sudo apt install linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)
sudo apt install sof-firmware
systemctl --user restart pulseaudio
sudo usermod -a -G audio $USER
echo "options snd-intel-dspcfg dsp_driver=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/intel-dspcfg.conf
echo "options snd_hda_intel power_save=0 power_save_controller=N" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/audio_disable_powersave.conf

I hope this could be of some help.
